# Cannot get results to display in python app

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is write a program that reads the numbers in a text file, displays the numbers and then displays the total of all the numbers in the file and lists the numbers in the file

```
'''
This program should total the random numbers you generated in the numbers.txt file and
then list them and give a total of the numbers
'''  
import random

def main():
    # open random number file
    number_file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    # initialize an accumulator
    total = 0.0

     #  Initialize a variable to keep count of the numbers
    count = 0

    # Get the values of the number file 
    for line in number_file:

        # convert a line to a float
        rand_number = float(line)

        # add 1 to the count variable
        count += 1

        # Add the time to total
        total += rand_number

    # Close the file
    number_file.close()

    print('The total of the numbers is ', total)
    print('There were' count + ' records')

# call main function
main()
```

I cannot get it to display the numbers nor give me the totals.  What do I need to correct to get this to do what I want it to do?

Comment: in your print line, you're trying to add "count", which is a number, to a string, that will raise an exception, also, while iterating through the file, you need to put number_file.readlines().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    print('There were ' + str(count) + ' records')
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2.7 or older version of python, you can use:

```
print 'There were', count, 'records'
```